# Валидное расположение блоков

Tags: css, bootstrap, html

Подскажите как грамотно расположить блоки как на данном рисунке(блок 3 немного заезжает на блок 1,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]), что б они сохранили при этом адаптивность свою(при изменении ширины экрана не проваливались ни куда). Можно и на бутстрапе, просто интересен грамотный подход, да бы минимизировать использование лишних тегов и стилей.Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[css - calc()](http://htmlbook.ru/css/calc)

[browser support calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

```css
.block-1 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.block-2,
.block-3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: calc(100% + 50px)!important;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .block-3 {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 block-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 block-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 block-3">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что за `calc` в `css`? Для каких браузеров работает?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Вместо `col-md-4 col-sm-4` достаточно `col-sm-4`. И поскольку бутстрап работает в логике "mobile first", органичнее использовать  `min-width` вместо `max-width`. Тогда `margin-left` и `width` для третьего блока понадобится определять только один раз - внутри `@media screen and (min-width: 768px)`.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос про минимизацию кода, предлагаю ещё один вариант.

Строил то же, что и [soledar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526991/208926). Отличия в деталях:

1. Второй и третий блоки не надо заворачивать в отдельную строку.
2. Вместо `calc` можно использовать проценты от ширины экрана.
3. Поскольку бутстрап рабоает в логике "mobile first", органичнее использовать `@media (min-width: 768px)`. Это позволяет задать `width` и `margin-left` для третьего блока только один раз, когда они отличаются от значений по умолчанию.
4. `col-sm-` действует для всех экранов шириной от 768 пикселей. Если при большей ширине экрана поведение не меняется, то другие классы добавлять не нужно.

```css
.block-red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
.block-green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
.block-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .block-yellow {
    margin-left: -10%;
    width: 85% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 block-red"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 block-green"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 block-yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```